# LU разложение неквадратной матрицы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, матрицы

На [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) LU разложение определено как разложение всякой матрицы в произведение двух квадратных матриц. Но как тогда сделать LU разложение неквадратной матрицы, и есть ли в этом смысл?

У меня есть следующий алгоритм, который работает для квадратных матриц, а также для матриц количество строк которых `N` `<` кол-ва столбцов `M`. Как можно его модифицировать, чтобы он работал для всех матриц?

```
for (size_t k = 0; k < N - 1; ++k) {
    for (size_t i = k + 1; i < N; ++i)
        if (std::abs(matrix[i][k]) > std::abs(matrix[k][k]))
            std::swap(matrix[i], matrix[k]);

    for (size_t i = k + 1; i < N; ++i) {
        matrix[i][k] /= matrix[k][k];

        for (size_t j = k + 1; j < M; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] -= matrix[i][k] * matrix[k][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, в приведённой вами ссылке на Википедию раздел Definitions начинается предложением "Let `A` be a **square** matrix.". К тому же, нельзя перемножив две квадратные матрицы, получить прямоугольную: если размерности двух квадратных матриц равны - то их произведение также квадратная матрица, если размерности двух квадратных матриц отличаются, то их нельзя перемножить.

Comment: LU квадратных матриц возникло не само по себе, а для решения вполне определенных прагматических задач, поэтому какую исходную задачу Вы хотите решить? Очевидно, что оно не имеет смысла, если число строк больше числа столбцов и не определено однозначно, если число строк меньше числа столбцов.